# how to compute the determinant of a Matrix in C using recursive functions

Tags: c, recursion, matrix, determinants

Hello I was trying to make a C program that calculate the determinant of a given matrix. I somewhat completed it but I got stuck when I was trying to make a function that finds the sub matrix of a given matrix and a component. I commented as clearly as I could in each part but I believe the main problem with the program is the last method subMatrix.If you could help me fix it or present an alternative solution i would really appreciate it.

PS :I know some part of the code or comments might not be clear ,so feel free to ask me any questions in the comments.

```
#define MAX 10000
    //here I was trying to make a "matrix" type to be able to return values in the function "subMatrix"
    struct Matrix
    {
        double a[MAX][MAX];
    };


    struct Matrix subMatrix(int n, double m[n][n], int I, int J);
    double determinant(int n, double M[n][n]);


    int main()
    {
        int n, k = 0;
        printf("how many rows does the matrix have"); 
        scanf("%d", &n);
        double Matrix[n][n];
        double temp[n * n];
        printf("enter the numbers in order with an enter after each one");
        //gathering all the data from the user
        for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", temp[i]);
        }
        //sorting the data into a matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Matrix[i][j] = temp[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
        //prints the determinant
        printf("%d",determinant(n,Matrix));

        return 0;
    }
    //this recursive function calculates the determinant 
    double determinant(int n, double M[n][n])
    {
        double det = 0;
        //the functions continues to call its self until n=2
        if (n == 2)
        {
            det = M[0][0] *M[1][1]-M[0][1]*M[1][0];
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                det += M[0][i] * determinant(n - 1, subMatrix(n, M, 0, i));
            }
        }



        return det;
    }
    //here I tried to make the subMatrix of a given matrix and one of its components
    //by sub matrix I mean the matrix that doesn't include the row and columns that are in line with one of the matrix componants
    struct Matrix subMatrix(int n, double m[n][n], int I, int J)
    {
        int i, a = 0, b = 0;
        int j;
        struct Matrix M[n - 1][n - 1];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i != I)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (J != j)
                    {
                        M[a][b] = m[i][j];
                        b++;
                    }
                }
                a++;
            }
        }
        return M;
    }
```

Comment: Have you done some debugging on `subMatrix`? You can breakpoint on a call to it and see what it actually is doing, or breakpoint inside to get more details. Why do you declare a 2D array of matrices within `subMatrix` (`struct Matrix M[n - 1][n - 1];`)?

Comment: Start by getting a clear idea of where/what a sub matrix is, to calculate the determinant of. I recommend looking at a matrix which is (N+1)x(N+1), where N is the largerst you want to calculate the determinant directly for. Draw the large one on paper, and then mark all the (NxN) sub matrices. By doing that drawing, you will get an idea of the algorithm and structures to find the subs.

Comment: @Yunnosch i think i got the logic right i just dont know how to return the newly made subMatrix back to the determinant function.what i was trying to do is to see if the i and j component are repeated and if not add it to the new submatrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code,

1. `subMatrix` is returning pointer of `struct Matrix` but expected to be just a `struct Matrix`
2. In `subMatrix`value of `b` is incremented and not reset on new row.
3. Argument for `determinant` expects `double M[n][n]`but passing `struct Matrix` in recursive call
4. redundant use of local variable `temp[n * n]`
5. wrong behavior on input `n=1`

Simple solution to get 2D array back from `subMatrix` is to pass the reference of 2D array and fill the required value inside the function.

I tried to simply the clutter as follows,

```
void subMatrix(int n, double m[n][n], int I, int J,double M[n-1][n-1])
{
    int i, a = 0, b = 0;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i == I)
        {
            continue;
        }

        b = 0;//in-order to start fresh for new row
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (J == j)
            {
                continue;
            }
            M[a][b] = m[i][j];
            b++;
        }
        a++;
    }
}

//this recursive function calculates the determinant 
double  determinant(int n, double M[n][n])
{
    double det = 0;
    //the functions continues to call its self until n=2
    if(n==1)
    {
        return M[0][0];
    }
    if (n == 2)
    {
        det = M[0][0] *M[1][1]-M[0][1]*M[1][0];
    }
    else
    {
        double subArray[n-1][n-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            //subMatrix is filling the subArray
            subMatrix(n,M,0,i,subArray);
            det += M[0][i] * ((i&1)?-1:1)*determinant(n - 1,subArray);
        }
    }
    return det;
}

int main()
{
    int n, k = 0;

    printf("how many rows does the matrix have"); 
    scanf("%d", &n);

    double Matrix[n][n];
    printf("enter the numbers in order with an enter after each one");

   //Taking user input for 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%lf", &Matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("%f",determinant(n,Matrix));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help i just didnt understand your 5th point what was wrong with n=1

Comment: By the way you forgot to put a pow(-1,i) in the determinant function

Comment: @AliAgharazi: `n=1` is condition when user gives matrix of size 1x1 and thanks for correction. i have updated the solution without `pow`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution i didn't post it sooner because i couldn't find out the mistake but thanks to @Truthseeker I figured out I wasn't letting b=0 and i got it to work this program can calculate the determinant but truthseekers answer is mathematically flawed because he forgot `pow (-1, i)` in the determinant method

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>


    void subMatrix(int n,double M[n-1][n-1], double m[n][n], int I, int J)
    {
        int i, a = 0, b = 0;
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i != I)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (J != j)
                    {
                        M[a][b] = m[i][j];

                        b++;

                    }
                }

                a++;
                b=0;
            }
        }

    }

    //this recursive function calculates the determinant
    double determinant (int n, double m[n][n])
    {

      double det = 0;
      //the functions continues to call its self until n=2
      if (n == 1)
        {
          return m[0][0];
        }
      if (n == 2)
        {
          det = m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[0][1] * m[1][0];
        }
      else
        {
          double M[n - 1][n - 1];
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
          subMatrix (n, M, m, 0, i);
          det += m[0][i] * pow (-1, i) * determinant (n - 1, M);
        }
        }

      return det;
    }

    int
    main ()
    {
      int n, k = 0;


      printf ("how many rows does the matrix have");
      scanf ("%d", &n);
      double Matrix[n][n];
      printf ("enter the numbers in order with an enter after each one");
      //Taking user input for 2D array
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
          scanf ("%lf", &Matrix[i][j]);
        }
        }

      //prints the determinant
      printf ("the determinant is %lf\n", determinant (n, Matrix));

      return 0;
    }
```